# Combine WCF, NHibernate and Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nhibernate, ninject

I'm writing a WCF service (hosted in IIS). I downloaded Ninject (3.0.0.0, with WCF extensions) and NHibernate from Nuget.
I have used these together in an MVC context, but not yet in WCF.
I would like to have have a new session per call to the service.
But I can't really find a good tutorial on how to accomplish it.

For now, I just put this in the "NinjectWebCommon.cs" file (like I do in my MVC projects)

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var helper = new NHibernateHelper(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xx"].ConnectionString, Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Template)));
    kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<IDbSessionFactory>().To<DbSessionFactory>().InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<IDbSession>().To<DbSession>().InRequestScope();

    //Repository
    //Bind the repository stuff here
}
```

But this is not really working as I would expect. Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

A bit more details. I can see that when my service starts, It fires up an NHibernate session object. But it actually fails on the dispose.
When it tries to close my session I get a NullReferenceException.
I'm using al the latest versions from Nuget.

Comment: Does nobody have an answer on this topic? Or a good example? It's getting quite urgent since the rest of my application is starting almost finished.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inherit the `Global` application class from `NinjectWcfApplication`.

```
public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{
    #region Overrides of NinjectWcfApplication

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel( new ServiceModule() );
        return kernel;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/tree/Maintenance_2.2/src/Examples

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm using a newer version of the WCF extensions, so this is not really valid anymore.